Catch-all rule for subdomains in Windows Server DNS
Windows Server 2016 DNS with forward lookup zone "test.contoso.com". I created an A record for test.contoso.com for the IP of "test2.contoso.com" to redirect users to "test2". I prefer using a CNAME for this, but Windows throws an error if you try this.
The A record ensures that only the "test2" subdomain is accessed by our users. Main problem is solved.
However it does not handle  "sub.test.contoso.com". The request does not go through our DNS server.  "NXDOMAIN" is returned when querying any subdomain of "test.contoso.com".
We are not sure why this is happening. Recursion  and root hints are enabled. We are using Cloudflare for DNS forwarders.
We can use "New Delegation" to manually delegate every known subdomain of test.contoso.com to the name servers of test.Contoso.com, but that doesn't seem like the "right way" to do things. We'd  rather have the DNS forwarders handle all cases that our local DNS servers don't have answers for.
We also tried looking into wildcards, but it didn't seem like you can do a wildcard DNS delegation.
How can we configure Windows DNS to handle every subdomain without  responding with NXDOMAIN?
Or is my thinking just wrong? I'm definitely not a DNS wizard, but I feel like I've exhausted several options here.

What is the ns record for test.contoso.com?  Does that point at your DNS servers? That should determine how it recurses.

We've put in NS records for contoso.com's name servers at the top of the zone, and we removed the generic, auto-generated NS records pointing to our local DNS servers--but for some reason Windows keeps re-adding the NS records for our local DNS back in every time the zone is refreshed.  Which complicates things.

There might be a way to stop the auto-generated NS records from being put there. I can try it tomorrow. If it works, I'll post it as an answer.

Okay, so I was able to use Dnscmd [local.dnsserver] /config test.contoso.com /AllowNSRecordsAutoCreation [Contoso NameServer IP] which successfully stops Windows from auto-generating NS records in that zone with the names of the local DNS servers / DCs.
But...same problem is occurring. NXDomain for lookup of any subdomains of test.contoso.com.
The recursion is still breaking down. @user189695
